# one-point compatification of $X$

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is called $T_B$ if every compact subset is closed.

Let $X$ be countable and $T_B$ and $X^* = X \cup \{\infty\}$ be one-point compatification of $X$.

We want to show that when $X$ is countable , $T_B$ space and sequential space. then $X^*$ is $T_B$. So we consider compact subset $B$ of $X^*$. We must consider two cases:

(1):$\infty \not\in B$

(2):$\infty \in B$

For the first case, it is easy to show that $X^*$ is $T_B$.

For the second case, if $\infty \in B$ and $B$ is not closed in $X^*$, so $C\cap X$ is not closed in $X$ and not sequential closed.then there is a sequence $\{ x_n \}$ s.t converge to $ a \not\in B$.....

> **could you help me how to reach a contradiction ?**

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$You can’t show that $X^*$ is $T_B$ by looking at one case; what you mean is that in the first case it’s easy to show that $B$ is closed in $X^*$. Now you have a compact set $B\subseteq X^*$ such that $\infty\in B$, you’re assuming that $B$ is not closed in $X^*$, and you want to reach a contradiction.

Let $C=B\cap X$; since $\infty\in B$, $C$ is not closed in $X$. $X$ is sequential, so $C$ is not sequentially closed, and there is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ in $C$ converging to some $x\in X\setminus C$. The set $\{x\}\cup\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ is compact (why?), so it’s closed in $X$, and therefore $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ is relatively closed in $B$. Now use the fact that $X$ is $T_B$: this implies that $X$ is $US$, i.e., that convergent sequences have unique limits, from which it follows that $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a discrete subset of $B$. Thus, $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a closed, discrete subset of $B$, contradicting ... what?

Comment: (1) what do you mean "**relatively closed**""?(2) is $x$ an accumulation point of $ \{ x_n : n \in \omega \}$?(3) is $\infty$ an accumulation point of $ \{ x_n : n \in \omega \}$?(4) if $\{x_n:n\in \omega\}$ is a closed, discrete subset of B, contradicting with compactness B?

Comment: @Ebi: (1) You should recognize that term by now: it means that the set is closed in the relative topology (also called the *subspace topology*) on $B$. (2) Yes, since $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle\to x$ and $x\notin\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$. (3) Yes, though it doesn’t matter. (4) Yes, exactly.

Comment: $A = \{ x\} \cup \{x_n :n \in \omega \}$ is closed in $X$. so $X^* - A$ is a nbh at $\infty$, how is $\infty$ accumulation point of $\{x_n:n \in ω\}$?

Comment: @Ebi: Sorry: for some reason I wrote *Yes* when I meant *No*. But it really doesn’t matter at all for the argument.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: fwiw I made it through several university courses in topology without having heard the term "relative topology" or "relatively closed". It was always just "subspace topology" and "closed" to me.

Comment: @Ben: Although the screen name is different, I’m reasonably certain that this isn’t the first time that I’ve explained the term to the OP. I’ve no objection to the term *subspace topology*, but *closed* is simply wrong: it must be *closed in the relative/subspace topology* or *closed in* $B$ (or whatever the subspace in question is). And I have a serious bone to pick with any text that (or instructor who) fails to mention both of the common terms, whichever one then gets used.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: pick all the bones you want, I'm just saying it happens :) (and yes, I would say "closed in $B$" if I wanted to be precise, but to me that is just using the term "closed" together with a specification of the topology it is closed in) [edit: in fairness, it's possible that someone once told me about "relative" to mean "subspace". But everyone then used "subspace", so I've entirely forgotten the former term if I ever knew it].

Comment: @Ben: The point is that in that setting you *have* to specify the topology, because it’s not the default topology. If you just say *closed*, you’re saying *closed in the whole space*. I grant that sometimes the context makes it pretty clear that the relative topology is intended, but it’s still better to avoid the formal ambiguity — **especially** for beginners!